# Parâmetro servidor php

Tags: php

Estou montando um esquema para validar meu código para tentar evitar copias. Me surgiu uma dúvida se teria algum parâmetro do Apache ou php que seria único... por exemplo se copiar o código fonte e rodar em outra máquina esse código mudaria...
Porque a minha ideia eh validar esse código em um sistema externo

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar tornar o código ilegível (obfuscate), mas isso também pode ser desfeito. Um exemplo de código deste tipo:

```html
protected function F8798a4a9($V4ba49586, $Vd75b70be=array())
{ $Vcdbd1ded = $this->F71555a34($V4ba49586, $Vd75b70be);
if (!empty($Vcdbd1ded))
{ $V5f3968da='SET ' . implode(', ', $Vcdbd1ded);
} else
{ $V5f3968da='';
} return $V5f3968da;
}
```

Aqui tem várias ferramentas que podem fazer isso:

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/569/top-5-best-open-source-php-code-obfuscator-libraries

Uma forma de evitar cópias seria alterar a forma de trabalho do sistema, ou seja, criar uma API onde você centralizaria todas as requisições no seu servidor, e o seu sistema PHP seria um cliente da API, onde para cada requisição teria uma "chave" fornecida por você, para identificar o cliente.

Isso também não é 100% seguro, mas daria um  controle sobre quem está utilizando o sistema. Uma desvantagem é que aumentaria a sua responsabilidade, já que todos os dados dos seus usuários estariam no seu servidor, já que as cópias que usam o sistema seriam executadas nos servidores dos clientes.

Comment: Eu estava querendo pegar a variável system do phpinfo para fazer uma validação caso tente rodar em outra máquina. Sabe me dizer como conseguiria isso?